# How to find the Frechet derivative of $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, c \mapsto \int H(t,c(t),c^\prime(t)) dt $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, frechet-derivative

> Consider an interval $I = [t_0,t_1]$ and a finite dimensional Banach space $X$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R} \times X \times X$ and let  $V \subseteq \mathcal{C}^{1}(I,X)$ be the set of all curves $c:I \rightarrow X$, where $(t,c(t),c^\prime(t))$ is contained in $U$ for all $t$. Let further be
>
> $$\lvert\lvert c \rvert\rvert_{\mathcal{C}^1(I)} := \sup_{t \in I} \lvert\lvert c(t) \rvert\rvert_X + \sup_{t \in I}\lvert\lvert c^\prime(t) \rvert\rvert_X.$$
>
> We note that $V$ is open in $\mathcal{C}^1(I,X)$.
> For a $\mathcal{C}^r$ function $H: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($r \ge 2$) consider the functional
> $$f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, c \mapsto \int_I H(t,c(t),c^\prime(t)) dt $$
> under side conditions $c(t_0) = x_0$ and $c(t_1) = x_1$. Find the Frechet derivative $Df_c$, where $C \in V$.

This setting strongly reminds me of [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). The (first) proof given in Wikipedia computes the total derivative of a pertubation of $c$. Is it possible to transfer this here?

Comment: You mean a perturbation of $c$?

Comment: You also mean $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I made an edit.

Comment: Once you prove $f$ is Frechet differentiable, then computing the Frechet derivative is easy using differentiation under the integral sign ($Df_c(\gamma)=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\Big\rvert_{\epsilon=0}f(c+\epsilon\gamma)$). And yes, this is very much like differentiating the action. Proving Frechet differentiability is slightly annoying though. Take a look at Henri-Cartan’s *Differential Forms*, Chapter 3 where he goes through the Euler-Lagrange equations in the Banach-space setting carefully.